# postGIS views, qGIS, qGIS python console

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

Using a win 7 machine, I have been revising tables in postGIS, then looking at the results in qGIS: with following script and run it in the qGIS python console.

```
import random
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
myLayer = "layer_name"
myPrimaryKey = "the_key_name"
uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","database_name","user","password")
uri.setDataSource("public",myLayer,"geom","",myPrimaryKey)
vlayer= QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),myLayer+str(random.randrange(0,600)),"user")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The problems I am running into are twofold:

1. Sometimes if I do not change the name of the table, the above script does nothing.  (The random # is there so that I can see if the script has added a layer and with a new name.)
2. More importantly, the above script rarely works with postgis "views," meaning that each time I want to revise a table, I must first drop it.  I'd rather be replacing views.  The problem relates to this line:

```
uri.setDataSource("public",myLayer,"geom","","apn")
```

It let's me specify a schema, "public;" but I cannot figure out a way to say whether a table falls under the next level, namely postGIS tables or postGIS views.  If I could do this, I would then be able to specify the name of the view.  Yes, DBManager is "aware" of postGIS views.  But I would like to know if the qGIS python console can work with postGIS views.

Comment: When you say rarely works, are you saying it sometimes works with views? The only difference I can think of with a table or view is that with a table, QGIS knows what to use for primary key.  I assume you are saying apn should be the primary key.  If apn is duplicated in your view, I think qGIS throws up an error cause it can't deal with duplicate keys.

Comment: Thank you!  My views do not have keys (and I don't know it they can have can).  However, "apn" was the incorrect name for table's key.   I updated the above script for a key name and it now works with postgreSQL views!  As far as "rarely works," I will have to test further.  I have experienced instances where the above script would not add a table, when I had repeatedly dropped a given table, re-created it using a select (but with using same name), and then used the above script to send it to qGIS.

Comment: Okay I'll upgrade my comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I can think of with a table or view is that with a table, QGIS knows what to use for primary key because it can infer it from the table primary key constraints.  With a view, since you can't specify a primary key, you have to give it a name of a field to use.

I assume you are saying apn should be the primary key. If apn is duplicated in your view (multiple records have same apn) or does not exist, I think qGIS throws up an error cause it can't deal with duplicate keys and has to have a key.