# How to create a valid QgsVectorLayer from a PostgreSQL view?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-2.18, postgresql-10

I am attempting to create a QgsVectorLayer with the same code as I am using for a PostgreSQL table, which works correctly and the isValid() method on the layer returns `true`.

```
uri=QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost","5433","xxx","postgres","xxx",QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)
uri.setDataSource("xxx","sv_demog","geom","id")
uri.setSrid("4269")
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"xxxx","postgres")
print('sv_demog layer is valid: %s' % (vlayer.isValid()))
```

The view selects from table where id is the primary key, and has a geometry column.

How do I make this work for a view?

I am using a PostgreSQL 10 database, and QGIS 3 (***Update***: Same behavior in 2.18).

Ref: 
[Loading Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers)

Answer (score 4):

Jay, I had the same problem. You have to specify the view's primary key. For example,
uri.setDataSource('my schema', 'my_view', 'geom', '', 'id')

Check out this thread [postGIS views, qGIS, qGIS python console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237799/postgis-views-qgis-qgis-python-console)